# git diff-tree and copy or xargs to a folder

Tags: bash, git, gitlab

I want to do something very simple.
Get all my committed files I pushed and copy without overwriting them to a specific folder on my repo.
I found the first command:

```
$ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA # list latest committed files inside my pipeline
```

Now I am stuck on the next step and not sure if it would work with:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | "xargs... or cp -vnpr" path/to/folder
```

If there is a bash I can use please let me know as well. I didn't really find anything pertinent to this.
THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: @ALL Thank you so much for your help!!  Those two commands achieved what I want. Especially this <git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | xargs -I {} cp '{}'>.  What I am actually trying to achieve now is to run a bash against the committed files to my repo and I will need the full path of those files before running the script. Something like this: ./regula.sh ../<path/to/committed-file> regula/lib regula/custom-rules. I know a simple bash script with some variables can do that for me but haven't found one. I will greatly appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are feeding `cp` command from stdin, so you need to use it with `-t`. The following command will do the trick for you:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | xargs -r cp -t /path/to/folder
```

Comment: You saved me ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | xargs -I {} cp '{}' /path/to/folder
```

Set the placeholders with -I and then construct the copy command.